# hide/unhide UIPicker with the same animation

Tags: ios, uipicker

im currently making a project where i need to hide my UIPicker, i've done all the hiding and animation stuff with this code,

on button press event this code is written:

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
    CGAffineTransform transfrom = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -200);
    self.picker.transform = transfrom;
    self.picker.alpha = self.picker.alpha * (-1) + 1;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

and on view did load initialized;

```
    self.picker.alpha = 0;
    [self.view addSubview:self.picker]; //i dont really need this one
```

so here the picker will appear from button to top (0,-200) but when i click the button again it dissapears right away as  self.picker.alpha goes to 0. i tried also putting animation delay and [UIView setAnimationDelay:3]; and tried also to set the animationDuration more but it does not effect when its going to hide.

i would like to know if how do i make the UIPicker hide in the same manner as it appears. 
hope its not so confusing.
thanx

Answer (score 1):

To reset the view to its original position you would want to reset the `transform` to `CGAffineTransformIdentity`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Wain mentioned, you have changed the `transform` property while appearing the `UIPickerView`.

When you want to disappear the Picker View on click of a button you need to set its transform again.

Here is a link to learn animation in UIView in iOS:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html